# Can gwt analyze dependency like maven does?

Tags: gwt, dependencies, inheritance, gwt-maven-plugin

How can I get GWT to provide the same dependency insights as  **mvn dependency:analyze**?

Maven can  report about dependencies (Used undeclared dependencies and Unused declared dependencies).   I'd like to get GWT to do the same because determining missing *inherits*  in my gwt.xml proves difficult.

Is there a good way for the system to analyze dependency state?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any such tool, and while I think a utility to analyze and report on GWT dependencies could be interesting, I also think it would be difficult to define well.

### Used, undeclared dependencies

Before trying to solve this, what is the problem? In maven, this category means that a Class is loaded from a dependency that isn't directly depended on, but instead is transitively loaded. This starts to get into the whole issue of transitive dependencies (which exist in GWT) and scopes (which don't). If A uses a class in C, but only depends on B, which depends on C, this will be listed in the 'used, undeclared dependencies' list.

In GWT however, we very rarely list every single dependency we use directly. Instead, we assume that transitive dependencies will stay transitive - we dont bother to inherit `com.google.gwt.user.RemoteService` for RPC as long as we already have `com.google.gwt.user.User` listed.

So how could we tell if we are using an undeclared dependency, the kind that warns when we do a `gwt:compile`? Perhaps such a tool could find every `.gwt.xml` file on the classpath, and read through its `<source>` and `<super-source>` rules to look for somewhere that a class we are using is declared? Or in the case of invoking `GWT.create` on something and getting back a non-concrete type, it could look for `<replace-with>` and `<generate-with>` rules. As long as your code already compiles in Java, the classes are on the classpath, but you still run the risk that while the class is there, the `.java` or `.gwt.xml` files might not be.

### Unused, declared dependencies

This seems like an easier problem - analyze the modules we are inheriting, and look through them for any module that could be pruned out. Unfortunately, as the above discussion notes, we can't just look for the classes and which package they are in, which `<source>` and `<super-source>` elements are unused - we also would need to look for `<replace-with>` and `<generate-with>` rules - consider something like `com.google.gwt.user.RemoteService`, which only adds a rule and some configuration details, or even `com.google.gwt.user.RemoteServiceObfuscateTypeNames`, which modifies only a single setting of the RemoteService module. If RemoteServiceObfuscateTypeNames were removed, everything would still compile, but now there might be information about your RPC classes compiled into your app that you don't expect to be there.

With these in mind, perhaps such a tool could watch all possible rebind rules in the current build, and all configuration settings, properties, etc, and see if any of those rules were not using during a `gwt:compile` process. Then, indicate which modules had unused parts, and if any module (and all of its inherited modules) were unused, it could shown to the user as able to be removed.

One more important piece: order matters, when defining `<inherits>` statements. If I add a inherits for `com.google.gwt.logging.Logging`, then follow it with `com.google.gwt.logging.LoggingDisabled`, logging classes will be on the source path and will compile, but will have no effect. But if those are ordered the other way around, then they will not only be on the source path, but will all be functional. So any analysis of modules used and unused would need to also include transitive inherits statements, and their orders.